# What's the `__version_info__ ` function in a PyPi package?

Tags: python, versioning

What's the `__version_info__` function?

I am reading a open source library [uritemplate](https://github.com/python-hyper/uritemplate/blob/master/uritemplate/__init__.py), I found:

```
__version__ = '3.0.0'
__version_info__ = tuple(int(i) for i in __version__.split('.') if i.isdigit())
```

there have `__version__` already, why there still define the `__version_info__` variable there? what's the function of it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried the test code:

```
__version__ = '1.1.1.20180726_beta'
__version_info__ = tuple(int(i) for i in __version__.split('.') if i.isdigit())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__version_info__)
```

the result is:

```
(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be useful to programmatically compare versions:

```
>>> '1.10.0' > '1.9.0'
False
>>> (1, 10, 0) > (1, 9, 0)
True
```

Importing code can then check for specific features:

```
import foolib
if foolib.__version_info__ >= (1, 9, 0):
    # this version supports super_cool_functionality
    foolib.super_cool_functionality()
else:
    print("upgrade foolib to get super cool functionality")
```

This isn't generally great, because it doesn't handle removals and other API changes well, so in practice you might instead want to require a more specific version that guarantees `super_cool_functionality` or use more direct feature detection:

```
if hasattr(foolib, 'super_cool_functionality'):
    # this version supports super_cool_functionality
    foolib.super_cool_functionality()
else:
    print("installed version of foolib doesn't have super cool functionality")
```

Python itself exposes a named tuple for its own version in [`sys.version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info).

Comment: more one question, is there possible of `1.1.1.20180726_beta` and `1.1.1.20180727_beta` version?

Comment: @aircraft what do you mean *"is there possible"*? Sure that could be a version number, but the code you've posted would ignore the `_beta` part when creating the tuple.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it, or preferably just post a new question?

Comment: @Robin See my edit.

Comment: @aircraft what is your question?

Comment: the __version__ is `'1.1.1.20180726_beta''1.1.1.20180726_beta'` but the `__version_info__ ` is `(1, 1, 1)`, there is no `20180726`.

Comment: Yes, that is because that code only keeps the parts __separated by dots (`.`)__ that consists only of digits. The last part is `20180726_beta`, which contains non-digit characters, so it is left off. Change it to `'1.1.1.20180726.beta'` to see the difference.